# Error: Can't update mongodb-community via brew

Tags: install, xcode, homebrew

I seem to have a problem with my MongoDB (`mongodb-community`), which I installed via `brew` on my Mac. I always get the following:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade
Already up-to-date.
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community 5.0.2 -> 5.0.3
==> Downloading https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-macos-x86_64-5.0.3.tgz
Already downloaded: /Users/mrx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/eee3a5dc0bcbf2ed17be0fb6f00d57accad27094993bee463748278c0d8cb3df--mongodb-macos-x86_64-5.0.3.tgz
==> Upgrading mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
  5.0.2 -> 5.0.3

Error: Your Command Line Tools are too outdated.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.0.

Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  SystemExit: exit
```

Now, I went and ran

```
softwareupdate --all --install --force
sudo xcode-select --install
```

without that fixing anything. Now, `xcode-select --version` gives me `version 2384`, `/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version` reports back `Xcode 13.0 Build version 13A233`, and there is no software update available (I'm running `Big Sur 11.6`). Finally, I also tried to manually download the command line tools from Apple only to find that a painfully long download and installation didn't do anything.

Anything I missed?

Comment: Did you try the `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` step per the long error message?